# Autopopulate via date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that I'm trying to figure out how to do what I want. Macros are not an issue and Im certain I will have to use vba for my needs but dont know enough to put a dent in what i want to do.

The Basic premise is as follows. I have a two sheet workbook, Sheet 1 contains the current date and two fields one for #of Calls and the other for # of completes. Sheet 2 has a series of dates (for the month) and the same 2 fields form sheet 1 for all the dates. What I want to happen is, depending on the date on sheet 1 then sheet 2 will autofill the proper fields for that date. Leaving all other fields alone. I cannot get it to where it will leave the rest of the spreedsheet alone (not blank them out or put 0) and only populate the correct date. 
I have uploaded a sample spreed sheet [here](https://sites.google.com/site/swiftlikeninja/test.XLS). If anyone could provide me with any direction I would be greatly appreciative. If anything is unclear then please ask for clarification. Thanks in advanced.

STP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may run this macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub r()
Dim c as Range

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A999")
 If c.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value Then
   c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value
   c.Offset(0, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c2").Value
 End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This is wonderful, You're code worked without so much as a simple edit. And its clear enough for me to re purpose into the final project. Kudos.